# Going from Bootstrap 2 => Bootstrap 3 ... Without Destroying Site Styles

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I inherited a codebase that was using a 2.x version of Bootstrap.  Recently I tried upgrading to Bootstrap 3 to fix a bug.  It fixed the bug, but now my site is a disaster.  Heading tags are bigger but not bold.  My drop-downs don't look drop-downs, and my buttons don't look like buttons.  And so on.

It seems to me that I have two options:

1. revert to Bootstrap 2, save my site, and find another way to fix my original problem (but then I'm stuck with 2 forever)
2. bite the bullet, spend hours comparing old site vs. new site and copying over all the styles from the old bootstrap in to a new `bootstrap-fixes.css`.

But, given that Bootstrap 3 has been out for awhile, I'm thinking maybe this is a solved problem (with a better solution than either of the above).  One idea I had was to use the bootstrap customizer, which let's you override the base bootstrap styles.  The only thing is, coming up with all of the customization options to customize Bootstrap 3 properly (ie. to look like Bootstrap 2) is about as much work as creating a `bootstrap-fixes.css`.

However, the customizer also takes a `config.json file`, which made me wonder:

1. Is there any publicly avaiable `config.json` for generating Bootstrap 3 styles that preserve the relevant Bootstrap 2 styles?
2. If not, is there any other way to get Bootstrap 3 JS, and some sort of matching CSS file (customized Bootstrap 3 CSS?  upgraded Bootstrap 2 CSS?  some sort of frankenstein's monster?) that will work with the JS, but not destory my site?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 2 is desktop first (graceful degradation). Bootstrap 3 was written from the ground up as mobile first (progressive enhancement). They are two completely different beasts. You need to re-design your site afresh mobile first with Bootstrap 3.

Here's an official list of what's changed:

[Migrating to v3.x](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/)

You could try using some kind of automated tool but personally I just wouldn't trust these to get it right.

Comment: That list is great, but unfortunately, it completely leaves out a lot of the really important changes (the ones that have nothing to do with classes, just plain old HTML element styles).  But at least now I understand why v3 is so different; thanks!

Comment: In each of these two versions, the order and logic of the media queries is the opposite ;-)